# Split and store in Perl

Tags: shell-script, scripting, perl

I have a file with this content:

```
Ref  BBPin      r:/WORK/M375FS/HMLSBLK4BIT0P0_0/LSVCC15
Impl BBPin      i:/WORK/M375FS/HMLSBLK4BIT0P0_0/LSVCC15

Ref  BBPin      r:/WORK/HMLSBLK4BIT0P0_0/LSVCC3
Impl BBPin      i:/WORK/HMLSBLK4BIT0P0_0/LSVCC3

Ref  BBPin      r:/WORK/HMLSBLK4BIT0P0_0/LSVSS
Impl BBPin      i:/WORK/HMLSBLK4BIT0P0_0/LSVSS

Ref  BBPin      r:/WORK/IOP054_VINREG5_0/R0T
Impl BBPin      i:/WORK/IOP054_VINREG5_0/R0T

Ref  BBPin      r:/WORK/IOP055_VINREG5_1/R0T
Impl BBPin      i:/WORK/IOP055_VINREG5_1/R0T
```

and the code I am running

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl                                           
use warnings;
use strict;

my @words;
my $module;
my $pad;
open(my $file,'<',"file1.txt") or die $!;   
OUT: while(<$file>){
    chomp;
    $pad =$', if($_ =~ /(.*)\//g);

    @words= split('/');
    OUT1: foreach my $word (@words){        
         if($word eq 'IOP054_VINREG5_0'){
             print "Module Found \n";
             $module=$word;last OUT;
         }
    }
}
print $module, "\n";
print ("The pad present in module is :");
print $pad, "\n";
```

But I want to display all the last words. How can I achieve this?
Expected output

```
 HMLSBLK4BIT0P0_0 
The pad present in module is LSVCC15
 HMLSBLK4BIT0P0_0
   The pad present in module is LSVCC3
 HMLSBLK4BIT0P0_0
 The pad present in module is LSVSS 
IOP054_VINREG5_0 
The pad present in module is R0T
  IOP054_VINREG5_0 
The pad present in module is R0T
```

What my code does it does display

```
IOP054_VINREG5_0 
    The pad present in module is R0T
```

Comment: Please be more explicit.  What are you trying to do, what output do you want, and what output are you getting? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no other processing of the data is needed, then you don't need Perl for this.  A simple `awk` script would be enough:

```
$ awk -F '/' '/^Ref/ { printf("%s\nThe pad present in module is %s\n", $(NF-1), $NF) }' file
HMLSBLK4BIT0P0_0
The pad present in module is LSVCC15
HMLSBLK4BIT0P0_0
The pad present in module is LSVCC3
HMLSBLK4BIT0P0_0
The pad present in module is LSVSS
IOP054_VINREG5_0
The pad present in module is R0T
IOP055_VINREG5_1
The pad present in module is R0T
```

This treats the input as `/`-delimited fields and outputs the last two such fields in a formatted text string for each line that starts with `Ref`.

---

With Perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    /^Ref/ || next;

    chomp;
    my ($module, $pad) = (split('/'))[-2,-1];

    printf("%s\nThe pad present in module is %s\n", $module, $pad);
}
```

Running it:

```
$ perl script.pl file
HMLSBLK4BIT0P0_0
The pad present in module is LSVCC15
HMLSBLK4BIT0P0_0
The pad present in module is LSVCC3
HMLSBLK4BIT0P0_0
The pad present in module is LSVSS
IOP054_VINREG5_0
The pad present in module is R0T
IOP055_VINREG5_1
The pad present in module is R0T
```

Comment: I want to store them in a variable as well

Comment: @Coolstrike See update.

Comment: not getting the output you are showing , I am getting the first 2 lines only.

Comment: @Coolstrike Well, then there must be something wrong.  I'm running on the data that you have in the question.

Comment: Your code is not running

Comment: @Coolstrike Well, what can I say? It works for me.  If you are running on data that is in any way _different from what you have in the question_, then I would expect it to perform differently.

Comment: Sorry, Bro that doesn't work in any way.

Comment: @Coolstrike And you're not helping me with debugging it either. Well, you have a piece of code that you know works for someone, maybe you can modify it to fit your needs somehow. You obviously know Perl.

Comment: Bro that data is in a file OK!. And I am using it with a file but it does not work, i will figure something out.

Comment: It worked! had some extra characters in file.